# What I'm doing wrong in following code so that the variable inside loop is not accessible outside loop?

Tags: php, loops, variables, for-loop, scope

I've following code snippet :

```
$photoCount = 0;
$group_id = $_GET['group_id'];
for( $page_no = 1; $page_no > 0; $page_no++) {
    $group_photos_object = Phpfox::getComponent(
        'photo.photos',
        array(
              'group_id' => $group_id,
              'page_no' => $page_no
        ),
        'controller'
    );
    $group_photos = $group_photos_object->data;                
    if (!empty($group_photos)) {
        $currentphotoCount = count($group_photos);
        $photoCount = $photoCount + $currentphotoCount;               
    } else { 
        break;
     } //echo "Count 1 is : ".$photoCount; die;                
  } echo "Count 2 is : ".$photoCount; die;
```

Let me explain the logic I've written.

Here I'm using a for loop to call the same function

```
$group_photos_object = Phpfox::getComponent(
    'photo.photos',
    array(
        'group_id' => $group_id,
        'page_no' => $page_no
    ),
    'controller'
);
```

again and again with incremented value of `$page_no`. At the same time I'm keeping the variable `$photoCount` updated with the sum of previous count and the `$currentphotoCount`. But the issue I'm facing is I'm not able to access the variable `$photoCount` outside the for loop.

I tried to trace the issue and came to know that. When the `$page_no = 1` it works fine and the variable is accessible outside the for loop as well but when the value of variable `$page_no` gets incremented during second iteration, the array `$group_photos` is empty this time. From here onwards the mess begins and I'm not able to access the variable `$photoCount` outside the loop. If I try to print its value inside loop(before closing brace of for loop) it gets printed but not outside the loop.

I think there is no issue with the logic I written but somewhere something is going wrong that I am not able to find out.

Can someone please help me in this regard?

Thanks.

If you have any other query regarding the issue I'm facing please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried using a step-through debugger?

Comment: @Dai:No, Sorry I don't have an idea about what the step-through debugger is.

Comment: @RayOldProf:I've not such thing in my profile. Might be you are talking about some other user's profile.

Comment: how is it not accessible? Is it an error or a wrong value?

Comment: please add the rest of code where you'trying to access $photoCount

Comment: @onerror : Look at my updated code.

Comment: @user2839497 So, what's the output?

Comment: @onerror:Some HTML data.

Comment: Possibly there's something wrong with quotes or open/close tags because as your code written it should give you the number of *$group_photos* received in iteration 1 as a result. Maybe it will help if you show us the whole php file